# how to check for a presence of a character in a byte array

Tags: python, arrays

This sounds too basic for me to ask but here goes. I have a bytearray. I want to check for the presence of let's say 'a' or 'A' in the array and print the count of them. I do the following but I don't see any even though I know there is 'a' in there -

```
a_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
count = 0
for x in a_bytes:
    if ( (x=='a') or (x == 'A') ):
        count = count+1

return count
```

Why doesn't the above code work? I printed out the byte values as integers and I see 65 repeating multiple times. 
Then again I try to convert the constant 'a' to integer using int('a') but I get an error --

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Comment: There is a type mismatch here, you compare `int` with `str`. Use `ord('a')` or `b'a'`, these can be compared with integers. Also, there is a `count` method for arrays so you could simply say `count = a_bytes.count(b'a') + a_bytes.count(b'A')`. Note that two loops are not necessarily slower because builtin methods can be optimized. Anyway, in case of small arrays it doesn't even matter, in some cases code readability is more important.

Comment: @pasztorpisti you should add that as an answer.

Comment: @thebjorn In case of overly simple questions I usually don't post answers, just tips.

Comment: @user220201: Reading again my previous comment: it contains some inaccuracy/mistake: `b'a'` can not be compared to integers, but you can use it with `bytearray` methods (for example with `bytearray.count()`).

Comment: @pasztorpisti certainly, but your tip above is a complete answer, and better than any of the other posted answers -- mine included. If you post it as an answer I can vote it up so other people will find it faster in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The values in the bytearray are stored as integers, not as hex representations.  You need to search for `65` or `97`, not `"A"` or `"a"`.

If you want to use this to look up strings, just use a list.  If you're not interested in the integer values of the bytes, a bytearray is not the right choice.  Also, if you use a list, you can just use the `.count` method of lists to directly count occurrences of a particular value.

Comment: you surely mean `65` or `97`?

Comment: I see. Why 15? The ascii value of 'A' is 65.

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this? I don't want to be looking up ascii values to use in my code everytime

Comment: Oh, I thought he meant the hex digit A.

Comment: @user220201: If you want to search for strings, why don't you just use a list (or set) of strings instead of a bytearray?

Comment: The input is obtained from a hex string, so its really a binary array that I am searching in.

Comment: @user220201: But are you using it to find bytes, or to find characters?  If you want to deal with strings, just convert all the integer values to strings and work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison isn't supported between `int` and `str` types. You are trying to compare a byte with a string or character. To get the unicode codepoint of a character you can use the `ord()` function. Note that a unicode codepoint is an integer between 0 and about 1 million (unlike the range of a byte that is [0-255]) but in case of some encodings used in your byte array (let's say ascii or utf-8) and in case of ascii characters the usage of `ord()` is OK. Introducing the relation between byte arrays and strings (encoding) is out of the scope of this answer.

A solution to correct your code is to replace `'a'` and `'A'` with `ord('a')` and `ord('A')` respectively as others recommended.

However instead of your solution I would do this:

```
count = a_bytes.count(b'a') + a_bytes.count(b'A')
```

This makes the code much simpler and readable in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Converting between characters and their integer-value and back is done with the functions `ord` and `chr`. So `ord('A') == 65`.

And as the byte-array stores the values as ints, the result is

```
 a_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
 count = sum(c == ord('A') or c == ord('b') for c in a_bytes)
```

This works because `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with strings and characters, you need to decode the byte data first:

```
a_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string).decode('ascii')
count = 0
for x in a_bytes:
    if x == 'a' or x == 'A':
        count += 1

return count
```